# How to Set title and delete dijit.form.select in tablecontainer

Tags: dojo

I'm creating a table container, to which i'm adding select widget,

```
var layout1 = new dojox.layout.TableContainer({
            showLabels: true,
            orientation: "horiz",
            cols : 2, 
            spacing: 5,
            style: "border: solid 1px LightBlue;",
            customClass : "tableContainer"
});

layout.placeAt(divContentNode);
```

Below is my select widget:

```
var ran = new dijit.form.Select(
    {
        id :"srz102" ,
        name : "ZEND100",
        title : "VAPORTforVA",
        maxHeight : '100',
        style:"width: 150px",
        required:true,
        options:v4
    }
);

layout1.addChild(ran);
```

But with this i didn't get title for select widget,so i added

```
layout1.layout();
```

which displayed the title for select widget

Now when i try to destroy select widget i'm not able to delete the title

```
dijit.byId("srz102").destroyRecursive();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you trying to get hold of select node and destroying. That's why your title is not deleting properly. Instead you should try catching its parent and then try destroying the child

If you are using dojo 1.7 + (AMD), you can use:

```
    require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(domConstruct){
      // Destroy a node byId:
      domConstruct.destroy("id");
    })
```

For recursive deletion you can use :

```
dojo.query("id").forEach(dojo.destroy);
```

However you need to traverse the parent dom-node and delete each of them.

Just FYI dojo.query is very useful to get hold of any node not limited to id, you can get hold through css class like below

```
dojo.query(".cssClass")
```

Further ref :http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/destroy.html